# What is a single word for mouth, eyes, ears and nose?

Tags: single-word-requests

These are essentially all the organs which are attached to a creature’s head.

The closest phrase I’ve come across are **head sensory organs**, however I was hoping there was a more formal and scientific single word to describe these.

To give this context: I’m busy programming a system class structure which I’d like to use the proper scientific names for. This should therefore be such that a nose, eyes, ears and mouth are all types of *word*. In this case, “face” would not work, since a nose is not a type of face.

Comment: _Face?_  After all, the skin between them is also a sensory organ on the head.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The issue is that I need these organs to be a type of *word*, and in your suggestion, a “nose” isn’t a type of “face”. To give it context, I’m programming a system which I’d like to follow the proper naming conventions! :)

Comment: Head orifices, maybe?

Comment: @Daniel You should include that extra information in the question - the better you can define what you want, the easier it is for people to make accurate suggestions.

Comment: There is no scientific word for this in English as it is not a concept that I can imagine being employed in modern science or medicine.

Comment: You mention "__organ__" in the question (qualified by a couple of adjectives).  Is there a reason that won't work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nose, ears, mouth and eyes can be called **features**. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/feature) has

> **feature**
>
> **1.1** (usually **features**) A part of the face, such as the mouth or eyes, making a significant contribution to its overall appearance.

> *By mapping the face and focusing on features such as the eyes, nose and mouth, the system should be able to identify and help track down the closest match.*

Comment: While not as scientific, this is definitely the best so far! Thanks! :)

Comment: Please also see this [ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88094/single-word-for-ear-nose-and-throat).

Answer (score -1):

not including the eyes, you could refer to it as the nasopharyngeal area, however this is dependant on context and use. The nasopharyngeal area is the part of the upper oesophagus that comprises the joining section between the nasal air passage and the maxillary air passage

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm pretty sure this also doesn't include the ears though. You're missing 2/4 (half) of what the question wanted to describe.